# Do any Windows IM clients support Adium styles?

Tags: windows, themes, instant-messaging, adium

I know I can't actually get [Adium](http://adium.im/) on Windows. Are there any Windows IM clients that at least support Adium styles, specifically [Contact List Styles](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=search&cat_id=4) and [Message Styles](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=search&cat_id=5)?

[Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) is heart-breakingly close, but as far as I can tell, it's not there yet:

- [Pidgin-WebKit](http://pidgin.im/) would be perfect, except it [doesn't seem to compile on Windows](https://answers.launchpad.net/pidgin-webkit/+question/44473).
- [adium2pidgin-themes](http://code.google.com/p/adium2pidgin-themes/) converts Adium Xtras into Pidgin themes, but only supports sound, status, and emoticon theme types:

  ```
  -t TYPE, --type=TYPE  type of theme, may be: auto, sound, status or
                        emoticon, default: auto
  ```
- The Pidgin project is considering [merging Pidgin-WebKit into Pidgin itself](http://theflamingbanker.blogspot.com/2011/08/major-changes-afoot.html), but that sounds like a long way off:

  > Most notably, we've been talking about merging the webkit integration
  >   branch into what will become 3.0.0. Eventually, this would allow the
  >   support of Adium's message styles, although it may not happen right
  >   away.

So, are there any Windows IM clients that support Adium styles today?

Comment: +1 for well done research. Too bad pidgin doesn't work, that's what I would have proposed.

Comment: Have you tried [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/) ?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had the time to test it out at all, but [emescene](http://blog.emesene.org/) supports windows, and apparently supports adium themes

from the changelogs on their site... for version 2.11.7

> - Plugins and themes can be loaded from ~/.config/emesene2/[plugins|themes]
> - Avatars for Google talk and Facebook
> - Mail access in Google talk
> - A new Windows installer
> - Unity launcher support
> - Fully supported Adium theme set. All the themes are now Adium style
> - Conversations don't close when the user is disconnected
> - Updated translations

Installing a adium theme seems to work with message styles, but i've not quite worked out how to use contact list styles yet.

Apparently instandbird appears to use [adium style styles](https://wiki.instantbird.org/Instantbird:Message_Styles:Differences_with_Adium) as well, but they may need to be [repackaged.](https://wiki.instantbird.org/Instantbird:Message_Styles:Conversion)

Comment: Thank you! I've gotten emescene to use an Adium message style by copying it to `themes\conversations`. As far as I can tell, it doesn't support contact list styles, but I'd love to be proved wrong on this. :)

Comment: yeah, that bit works. I can't seem to get contact list styles working yet, but it seems to use the same formats.

Answer (score 1):

If Pidgen isn't doing it for you, try [Miranda](http://www.miranda-im.org/) or [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/).

If you need assistance in using any of the software listed above, just post a comment, and I'll include all the information you need to know.

Comment: Are you saying Miranda and/or Trillian support Adium styles?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying.  (Try one, if it doesn't work the way you want, try the other.)

Comment: Ok, I'm giving Miranda a try and now I'm in a maze of twisty plugins, all alike. :) Which of the [SRMMs](http://wiki.miranda-im.org/SRMM) supports Adium Message Styles? Which of the [contact list plugins](http://wiki.miranda-im.org/Customise:contact_list) will load Adium Contact List styles? (I'm guessing the answer is *not* Modern Contact List, since the Miranda addons site has several [ports](http://addons.miranda-im.org/details.php?action=viewfile&id=2478) of select Adium Contact List styles, none of which are the ones I want.)